# cordova platform add android error on Windows 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, cordova

I am using phonegap and have just started going through this [tutorial here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).

I am trying to add Android platform and getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Manu>cd hello

C:\Users\Manu\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Manu\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
 :126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
at C:\Users\Manu\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47:27
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:966:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you have `apache ant` installed, and check that you have `C:\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin` (or whatever the path is) in your `PATH` for `environment variables`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually the adt path is not recognised, follow below steps.

I am sharing with you the steps to create android PhoneGap app with cordova 3.4 version :-

1) Download and install Node.js.

2) Run this command on your terminal :-

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

3) Then create your project using following command :-

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

4) Then before adding any platform , run the following command....Replace the path of android sdk with your system path :-

```
$ export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/taruna/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/taruna/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
```

5) Now add your platform using following command :-

```
 $ sudo cordova platform add android
```

6) Now you can successfully run your project on emulator using following command :-

```
 $ cordova emulate android
```

And its done now.

Comment: this is a mac answer, he is using windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an Apache Ant installation.

1. Install Ant --> [link](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)
2. Set environment variable `ANT_HOME` which points to the `bin` directory of your installation path
3. add this variable to your `PATH` environment variable

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that it was due to a [bug in Ant](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43971). My Classpath ended with a " too, and I had to fix this by updating my class path. Instead of:

```
"C:\Program Files\Something\here"
```

I used:

```
C:\Progra~1\Something\here
```

and now it works.